# Change Power Point layout in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm doing some VBA work. In VBA, there are Application, Presentaion, Slide, Window objects. Their corresponding documents are poorly constructed so I'm confused how can I organize all my show into a templated manner, in which, original presentation slides are placed in the center with margin on four sides and have a short description and a image beneath the slide. Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This isn't easy to do, either with VBA or manually. PowerPoint isn't a flowdocument like Word where you can increase/decrease a page margin and the content will size/flow automatically.

Comment: @Otaku Then is there any work around do you think fit my needs? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would be the simplest of all would be to save each slide as an image and then place those images on blank slides resized to about 75% of the original slide and placed in the center so that you have blank space on all four sides where you could put textboxes, etc in those margins. It's not a great solution, but probably the fastest.

Comment: @Otaku: Okay, Thank you. Why don't you put this as an answer and let me close this topic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't easy to do, either with VBA or manually. PowerPoint isn't a flowdocument like Word where you can increase/decrease a page margin and the content will size/flow automatically.

The only thing I can think of that would be the simplest of all would be to save each slide as an image and then place those images on blank slides resized to about 75% of the original slide and placed in the center so that you have blank space on all four sides where you could put textboxes, etc in those margins. It's not a great solution, but probably the fastest.